# Magic functions __call() for functions?

Tags: php, function, magic-function

The magic function __call() in php are used in classes. Are there any similar magic function but for functions instead? Like __autoload() is for functions.

For example something like this

```
function __call($name, $arguments) {
    echo "Function $name says {$arguments[0]} ";
}
random_func("hello");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, I don't think such a magic function exists.

One workaround for this would be to put your functions into a static class, and add a [`__callStatic`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) magic method to that class (> PHP 5.3 only, I'm afraid):

```
class Func
 {
   /**  As of PHP 5.3.0  */
   public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
     {
    // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
    echo "Calling static method '$name' "
         . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";

  }
 }

Func::random_func("hello!");
```

For PHP < 5.3, you could do the same thing, but you would have to instantiate an object and use the `__call` magic method.

```
$Func = new Func;
$Func->random_func("hello!");
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Calling a function that doesn't exist will **always** result in a FATAL error.

** Maybe a zend extension can intercept this with a `fcall_begin_handler`, but I'm not sure.