# Wildcards in PHP functions

Tags: php, function

I am not sure if the term "Wildcard" can explain my point, but sometimes in some ready scripts we are able to call a non defined function like `find_by_age(23)` where age can be anything else that's mapped to a database table record. So i can call `find_by_name`, `find_by_email`, `find_by_id` and so on. So how can we do such thing either in procedural or object oriented ways ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magic functions __call() for functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456763/magic-functions-call-for-functions)

Comment: TIP: you should index the fields you search the table with. The bigger the table (number of fields, variable sizes (varchar) and blob types, number of rows) the longer a full table row search takes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you are looking for is *magic method*.

Basically like this:

```
class Foo {
    public function __call($method,$args) {
        echo "You were looking for the method $method.\n";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar(); // prints "You were looking for the method bar."
```

For what you are looking for, you just filter out bad function calls and redirect good ones:

```
class Model {
    public function find_by_field_name($field,$value) { ... }
    public function __call($method,$args) {
        if (substr($method,0,8) === 'find_by_') {
            $fn = array($this,'find_by_field_name');
            $arguments = array_merge(array(substr($method,8)),$args);
            return call_user_func_array($fn,$arguments);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Method not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `new Foo()->bar()` allowed?

Comment: `new Foo()->bar()` results in a syntax error: "unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)". This is true in both PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4. I haven't tried it yet in PHP 5.5.

Comment: I just confirmed that this is still a syntax error in PHP 5.5, but they did fix string/array dereferencing (like `foo()[3]` or `'xyz'[1]`), which is a similar issue.

Comment: You should surround new Foo() with another () like this: (new Foo()) ->bar();

Answer (score 1):

You can use them by defining a [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) magic method in your class, you can use them only in classes. on global scope

Quoting from PHP Manual:

```
<?php
class MethodTest {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling object method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }

    /**  As of PHP 5.3.0  */
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling static method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }
}

$obj = new MethodTest;
$obj->runTest('in object context');

MethodTest::runTest('in static context');  // As of PHP 5.3.0
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Calling object method 'runTest' in object context
Calling static method 'runTest' in static context
```

Answer (score 0):

For a procedural solution you can simply use string concatenation to get the job done. You can also fancy things up a bit by calling it an implementation of the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

```
<?php

/**
 * Employ a find by name strategy
 */
function find_by_name($name)
{
    echo "You are searching for users with the name $name";
    return array();
}

/**
 * Employ a find by age strategy
 */
function find_by_age($age)
{
    echo "You are searching for users who are $age years old";
    return array();
}

/**
 * Find users by using a particular strategy
 */
function find_using_strategy($strategy='age', $parameter)
{
    $results = array();
    $search_function = 'find_by_' . $search_field;
    if (function_exists($search_function)) {
        $results = $search_function($parameter);
    }

    return $results;
}


$users = find_using_strategy('name', 'Matthew Purdon');
var_dump($users);
```