# Global "method_missing" in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, method-missing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magic functions __call() for functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456763/magic-functions-call-for-functions)

I can implement __call() to provide method_missing behavior in PHP classes. Is there some way to provide the same functionality in the global scope?

I want something like this:

```
function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
  echo( sprintf( '%s called', $name ) );
}

echo( 'before' );
call_undefined_function( $a, $b );
echo( 'after' );
```

Outputs:

```
before
call_undefined_function called
after
```

Comment: don't worry - I found it only because I answered it...

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and use `function_exists()` in it to generate the message you want. As long as you don´t stop your script in your error handler, execution will continue.

Comment: I don't think that will handle undefined function errors. I tried `php -r "set_error_handler('var_dump'); d();"` this will fail (error handler won't get called, fatal error message), while `php -r "set_error_handler('var_dump'); echo $undefVar;"` works as expected.

Comment: @aularon, I hadn´t tried it, but it seems there are several kinds of errors that can´t be handled by a user-defined function, so I guess it won´t work after all...