# Is it possible to have a callback for a undefined object?

Tags: php, callback, undefined

Is it possible to define a function that get's called when a object isn't defined? So I can do `$makeUpOntheFlyObjectNames->something();` in the function get the object name, and the function name and a array of it's arguments, or a empty array if it has none. For what it was trying to call? Had an idea to make stuff like `$varName->length();` work in V5.x for strings and stuff. Was trying to Google this but was getting stuff like `class_exists` and stuff back, so figured a human would have a better answer. But I don't think it's possible, just wanted to check here to be sure.

So if the object wasn't found, and was calling length, check if it's a string and then return the result of strlen, else if it's not a string emulate php's own error.. Just some idea I had, but not sure if the first part of detection is even possible.

Comment: You could work some autoload magic.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't currently possible unless you have the ability to modify the classes you want this behaviour in (using the `__call` magic method). There isn't anything that can step in globally *(even the error handling functions don't trigger for missing methods)* -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456763/magic-functions-call-for-functions -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865865/are-there-equivalents-to-rubys-method-missing-in-other-languages

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$objName = 'test';
//check if the object exists
if(isset($$objName)){
//object exists...
}
else{
//do what you want here
}
```

try to run it "as is" or add a line before this code, for example:

```
$test = array(1=>'a',2=>'b');
$objName = 'test';
...
```

and see how you "fall" into the "if" instead of the "else"